# browser mode with foreach %dopar%

Tags: r

Is there a way to enter browser mode in a parallel foreach call?  I've tried to create a cluster using `manual = TRUE`.  As expected, it requires me to manually launch instances of R.  However, once the instance receive a task from the master process, its off the the races and doesn't seem to pause at the browser() command.  I'd like to enter browser and inspect the state of R.

```
foreach( i = 1 : 5 ) %dopar% 
{
     browser()
}
```

Here's the Rscript call in manual mode:

```
c:/.../bin/x64/Rscript" -e "parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()" MASTER=localhost PORT=10187 OUT= TIMEOUT=2592000 METHODS=TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `manual = TRUE`, load new instances of R (one for each node in your cluster), and execute the following:

```
timeout = 2592000
parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()
```

So basically ignore the RScript instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not stated in `?browser`, I would expect that `browser` only works in interactive sessions.

Comment: Perhaps the rscript call that is displayed when manual=TRUE can be modified to make R run interactively?

Comment: I added the rscript call to my original post

Comment: @SFun28: You can't make R run interactively via Rscript.  From `?Rscript`: "Options '--slave --no-restore' are always supplied: these imply '--no-save'".

Comment: ah...thanks!  Sounds like I need to find a way to run this interactively

Comment: Joshua - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Posted the solution.