# R mclapply vs foreach

Tags: r, foreach, mclapply

I use mclapply for all my "embarassingly parallel" computations.  I find it clean and easy to use, and when arguments `mc.cores = 1` and `mc.preschedule = TRUE` I can insert `browser()` in the function inside `mclapply` and debug line by line just like in regular R.  This is a huge help in getting code to production quicker.

*What does `foreach` offer that `mclapply` does not?  Is there a reason I should consider writing foreach code going forward?*

If I understand correctly, both can use the `multicore` approach to parallel computations (permitting forking) which I like to use for performance reasons.

I have seen `foreach` being used in various packages, and have read the basics of it, but frankly I don't find it as easy to use.  I also am unable to figure out how to get the `browser()` to work in `foreach` function calls.  (yes I have read this thread [browser mode with foreach %dopar%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483269/browser-mode-with-foreach-dopar) but didn't help me to get the browser to work right).

Comment: one reason we sometimes use `foreach` rather than `parallel` is the simple fact that `mclapply` does not work by default under windows (and many users still use windows). Although I could perform OS detection, as you noticed it also requires functions to be implemented a bit differently.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is almost the same as described here: [Understanding the differences between mclapply and parLapply in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196261/understanding-the-differences-between-mclapply-and-parlapply-in-r) .

The `mclapply` is creating clones of the master process for each worker processes (threads/cores) at the point that `mclapply` is called, reproducibility is guaranteed. Unfortunately, that isn't possible on Windows where in contrast to multicore there is always used the multisession parallelism by `foreach` or `parLapply`.

When using `parLapply` or `foreach` with `%dopar%`, you generally have to perform the following additional steps: Create a PSOCK cluster, Register the cluster if desired, Load necessary packages on the cluster workers, Export necessary data and functions to the global environment of the cluster workers.

That is why `foreach` has parameters like `.packages` and `.export` which enable us to distribute everything needed across sessions.

`future` package provided details of differences between mulicore and multisession processing  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-1-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

As Steve Weston (author of `foreach`) says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902796/foreach-dopar-rpostgresql/24634121#24634121), using `foreach` with `doParallel` as backend you can initialize workers. This can be helpful for setting up a database connection more efficiently once per worker instead of once per task.